# Here's an editing conflict case, how could we avoid it?

Tags: discussion

I have suggested this [edit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55818) and it has been rejected by Community.

Later, [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/68755/revisions) similar edit was accepted even if it has a small typo (in the name Jamie that is actually Jaime).

Comment: Looks like two of you were editing at the same time...I think that results in a "Community" rejection. It says *"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."*

Comment: Yes, @Paulie_D I know really know what that exactly mean... Cearon O'Flynn even accepted my edit, then a few minutes after, his edit is accepted. It looks my edit was submited before his.

Comment: It takes more than one user to accept an edit. Users with over 2K rep don't need to have their edits accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to make a guess, the order of operations was something like:

1. Cearon O'Flynn was reviewing edits. Saw yours and approved it.
2. Then noticed another minor edit that needed to be made and manually navigated to the edit page and submitted an edit. Because he has >2000 reputation, his edits aren't reviewed. Doing this nuked your edit suggestion.

This is based on the fact that the Community reject vote occurred at the same exact time as Cearon's edit was submitted.

*Normally*, what reviewers should do if they notice that additional edits need to be made is "accept and edit". Occasionally, we hit the "accept" button and miss an edit (as in your case, it reads "about Joffrey's" which should be "of Joffrey's").

In future, I would recommend that users not circumvent the edit block that exists when a suggested edit is pending for **exactly this reason**.